# JMeter - running thread in local and remote alternatively

Tags: jmeter

I am very new to JMeter.
My test plan has 3 parts.

1. Setup of the application on a remote machine. (I am using OS Process
   Sampler to execute a script file)
2. Run sampler from local machine.
3. Post test setup on remote machine. (I am using OS Process Sampler to execute a script file)

I have 3 threads.Now when I run this complete plan, I want the first thread to run on a remote machine, second thread in local machine and third thread in remote machine again.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: TO execute the script in remote box , i got [ssh Sampler](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-ssh-sampler/) .. I can used this to execute my script in remote box. Only problem is , the script cannot be executed with only my credential, after login i need to sesu in and then only can execute this. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))

> In computer science, a **thread** of execution is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler, which is typically a part of the operating system.

JMeter Threads are basically Java Threads which in their turn are underlying operating system threads. Hence you cannot run one thread on one machine, and another one on another.

Something you can do:

1. Use [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to setup application on remote machine. You can use OS Process Sampler to kick off a local program which will trigger remote deployment or something like that
2. Once program is started (you can use [Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) to wait) if program from step 1 runs in background) you can execute main test logic in the main [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
3. Use [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to run post setup tasks.

Another option could be using [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) and have slaves on 1st and 2nd machine and some crazy logic in test which uses combination of i.e. [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function, something like:

- If this machine IP == 10.10.10.1 - run that sampler
- If this machine IP == 10.10.10.2 - run another sampler

but it's kind of edge case.

Comment: Thanks for elaborative explanation

Comment: TO execute the script in remote box , i got [ssh Sampler](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-ssh-sampler/) .. I can used this to execute my script in remote box. Only problem is , the script cannot be executed with only my credential, after login i need to sesu in and then only can execute this. Any idea on how to do this?